# i have a scatter chart i want to delete the selected point in that

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is code for chart Displaying along with data but i need to delete selected point in the scatter chart.yell me the logic how to proceed this one..

```js
<html>
  <head>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart()
   {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Age', 'Weight'],
          [ 8,      12],
          [ 4,      60],
          [ 11,     14],
          [ 4,      80],
          [ 3,      40],
          [ 6.5,    7]
        ]);

        var options =
  {
          title: 'Age vs. Weight comparison',
          hAxis: {title: 'Age', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
          vAxis: {title: 'Weight', minValue: 0, maxValue: 15},
          legend: 'none'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  
        chart.draw(data, options);
  
     }                                         
    
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

i want to delete selected point from the scatter chart can i know the logic of how to proceed this one